# How to create a USB Ubuntu boot device from OSX for PC?

Tags: boot, live-usb, usb-drive, macbook, boot-repair

My Dell XPS 9350 is not booting Ubuntu anymore. It did not have dual boot but single boot only and the ssd is encrypted.

I am trying to create an Ubuntu bootable usb stick from Mac Apple OSX but until now all attempts failed.

I formatted the pendrive to `MS-DOS`.

Can I use directly the `iso` image file i.e.,

```
sudo dd if=Downloads/ubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/rdisk2 bs=1m
```

or as I have read elsewhere, should I convert the `iso` file:

```
hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o Downloads/ubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-amd64 Downloads/ubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso
```

which creates `Downloads/ubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-amd64.dmg`:

```
sudo dd if=Downloads/ubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-amd64.dmg of=/dev/rdisk2 bs=1m?
```

Comment: Check [this tutorial](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Prepare the USB stick**

*(You can skip this step if you intend to use the USB stick with only generic PC hardware.)*

-*Launch Disk Utility from **Applications>Utilities** or **Spotlight search***

-*Insert your USB stick and observe the new device added to Disk Utility*

-*Select the USB stick device* (you may need to enable the option **View>Show All Devices**) *and select Erase from the tool bar* (or right-click menu)

-*Set the format to* `MS-DOS (FAT)` *and the scheme to* `GUID Partition Map`

-*Check you've chosen the correct device and click Erase*

**2. Install and run Etcher**

To write the ISO file to the USB stick, I suggest Etcher (you can download it from this [link](https://www.balena.io/etcher/)).
After downloading this and clicking to mount the package, Etcher can either be run in-place or dragged into your Applications folder.

**3. Etcher configuration**

Etcher will configure and write to your USB device in three stages, each of which needs to be selected in turn:
-*Select image*: select the ISO image of Ubuntu.

-*Select drive*: select your USB drive.

-*Flash!*: press that button to make your USB drive bootable (you will be asked to provide your password).

After entering your password, Etcher will start writing the ISO file to your USB device.
When everything has finished, you will be notified.

**Credits:** [Create a bootable USB stick on macOS](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#0)